# How to do a lookup for the four primary keys columns yet output 6 columns to OLE DB Command

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm moving from a SQL Server database to a DB2 database. I'm trying to compare the primary key of the SQL Server database with the DB2 database and if its the same primary key values then do an update if they are not the same do an insert.

My problem is when I use a lookup for the primary key (first four columns) it only returns the first four columns, I need someway of getting the other two columns so I can run a OLE DB command and do the update.

I want to compare the four primary keys columns (`FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE, SYSTEM_ID, SYSTEM_CODE`) and see if they exist in the destination table if they do I want to update two other columns (`LOC_NAME, ALIAS_NAME`) and if they don't match I want to do an insert.

This is what I have for the lookup currently but it matches all the columns I just want to do the first four (`FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE, SYSTEM_ID, SYSTEM_CODE`) but output 6 columns (`FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE, SYSTEM_ID, SYSTEM_CODE, LOC_NAME, ALIAS_NAME`) to OLE DB Command so I can do an update:

```
SELECT 
    FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE, SYSTEM_ID,  
    SYSTEM_CODE, LOC_NAME, ALIAS_NAME 
FROM 
    LC1U1.Location_Supertbl1;
```

This is the update command I want to execute:

```
UPDATE LC1U1.Location_Supertbl1 
SET ALIAS_NAME = UPPER('test') 
WHERE FISCAL_YR = ? 
  AND LOC_CODE = ? 
  AND SYSTEM_ID = ? 
  AND SYSTEM_CODE = ?
```

How do I do this with a Lookup transformation in SSIS?

Thank you.

Comment: It is is the same DB and all fields are available from the table, why not just use a Stored Procedure?

Comment: I don't understand your statement about not using a Lookup Transformation. Can you help me understand the problem with using it?

Comment: I'm moving from a SQL Server database to a DB2 database. I'm trying to compare the primary key of the SQL Server database with the DB2 database and if its the same primary key values then do an update if they are not the same do an insert.

Comment: My problem is when I use a lookup for the primary key(first four fields) it only returns the first four fields, I need someway of getting the other two fields so I can run a OLE DB command and do the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're not asking for the columns from the lookup component.

In the UI, you drag lines between the left (Source) and right (Lookup) side. This defines the equality match for the lookup.

What you want to do is check the 2 additional columns in that menu, something like the following image. This will add LOC_NAME and ALIAS_NAME as new columns, after the Lookup Component, into my data flow

[image]